# MySql Error 'max_allowed_packet' bytes during import SQL script on database hosted on AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, mysqlimport, max-allowed-packet

I was facing an issue during import SQL file on MySql database which is on AWS RDS, during import SQL file initial table was imported then suddenly it shows an error.

[image]

I know this error and I can solve this by increasing max_allowed_packet size in MySQL config but is not local Mysql is AWS RDS show how can I do?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

After reviewing this article https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html I understand what I have to do and how.

Here are the following steps.

**1)** Go to RDS page and click on **"Parameter groups"** text located in the left navigation.

[image]

**2)** Now create a new group by clicking on **"Create parameter group"** orange button.

[image]

**3)** Fillup parameter group form **"Parameter group family"** should be MySql version of your RDS instance than **"Group name"** and **"Description"** whatever you want.

[image]

**4)** New "Parameter group" was created as **"test"** now edit it and increase **"max-allowed-packet"** by entering **"10000000" (10 MB)** value should be in **Bytes** after entering value don't forgot to click on **"Save changes"** button and make sure value is between **1024 Bytes to 1073741824 Bytes (1073 MB)**

[image]

**5)** Now you can see your changes by click on **"Preview changes"** button.

**6)** Now we have to change **"Parameter group"** of our RDS instance. SO, modify an instance and select **"Parameter groups"** which we created.

[image]

**7)** Now after modify RDS instance you should to **Reboot** it to apply your changes.

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough post!

Comment: Great answer, a couple of things to note in case folks are curious like me. Yes you need to create a new parameter group, you can't edit the default, and yes you need to reboot, parameter group doesn't go into effect otherwise

Comment: N.B. if you are updating a non-default parameter group attached to the db, no reboot is required.

Comment: With mariaDB in RDS, I can confirm that with non-default parameter group attached to the db, no reboot is required.

Answer (score 3):

Go to RDS, select *Parameter Groups* and create new group/edit existing one. Search for `max_allowed_packet` and enter new value for it. Attach this parameter group to RDS instance.